# How to create new columns based on a grouping method for one column in Polars?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have some data structed as showed at the first picture. Where I like to restructure the dataframe.
[image: initial data:]
Short piece of the initial data:

| id | time | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2050 | 02-01 | 20 |
| 2051 | 02-01 | 25 |
| 2050 | 02-02 | 21 |
| 2051 | 02-02 | 22 |
| 2051 | 02-03 | 23 |

The way I would like the restructured dataframe is with a timestamp column and then a column for each externallogid. I have done it with use of pandas, but since the file is quite huge, and must be used multiple times, I will like to do it in Polars due to the speed.

Excpected output:

| time | 2050 | 2051 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02-01 | 20 | 25 |
| 02-02 | 21 | 22 |
| 02-03 | nan | 23 |

I have tried an use the groupby function, and join/hstack/concat. But seems to have problems when also trying to use Lazyframes.

Thanks

To produce the data:

```
import polars as pl

lf = pl.DataFrame({'id': [2050, 2051, 2050, 2051, 2051],
                    'time': ['2023-05-01',
                             '2023-05-01',
                             '2023-05-02',
                             '2023-05-02',
                             '2023-05-03'],
                   'value': [20, 25, 21, 22, 23]})
lf = lf.with_columns(pl.col("time").str.to_datetime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: can you make your example reproducible please? and include expected output

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reproducible my example. But have include a short code to create the data, to my post.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can you show your expected output please?

Comment: It should be applied now

Comment: thanks! whoever voted to close, I suggest removing the vote, the question is good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pivot;

```py
In [29]: lf.pivot(columns='id', values='value', index='time', aggregate_function=None)
Out[29]:
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬──────┬──────┐
│ time                ┆ 2050 ┆ 2051 │
│ ---                 ┆ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞═════════════════════╪══════╪══════╡
│ 2023-05-01 00:00:00 ┆ 20   ┆ 25   │
│ 2023-05-02 00:00:00 ┆ 21   ┆ 22   │
│ 2023-05-03 00:00:00 ┆ null ┆ 23   │
└─────────────────────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Thanks alot! :)
Seems like I have some readings to do about pivot.